# Using files as an input in java

Tags: java

I need my program to run by using "java RunProgram list" command, RunProgram is the name of the main class of my program and "list" is the text file I'm using. Question is, what do I need to do in my program in order for that to work?

Comment: You need a `public static void main(String[])` method in your `RunProgram` class.

Comment: A multitude of things - you need to be reading from `args[]`, and you need to have appropriate IO written in the method you're reading from the file.  What do you have so far?  Is there a particular stumbling block you're hitting?

Answer (score 1):

```
java RunProgram list
```

So RunProgram will be the class and list will be the filename so you can get this file name in the main method as argument parameter and you can access it using `args[0]`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String file_name = args[0];  //list pass in cmd will be set in file_name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this java class:

```
import java.io.*;
Public Class RunProgram 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = args[0];  
        System.out.println(fileName);
        //Perform File Operation, whatever you want to perform.
    }
}
```

Now compile this java file by `javac RunProgram.java`
and run it by `java RunProgram list`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the command line arguments. In your RunProgram class, you have a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This method takes in arguments (via String[] args), which you can use just like any other method.

There are many ways to handle the input, (BufferedReader, Scanner, etc.) but the general idea is to check if the argument is passed in by checking on

```
args[0] // The first String element in the argument
```

If it is not null or empty, then you would try to use that argument as a fileName input.